# chaining in jquery is not working with jquery

Tags: jquery

i'm chaining a jquery selector. This is my code

```
$('[name="comp_detail_id[]"]').get(0);
```

This line of code gives me this result in the console.

```
<input type="hidden" name="comp_detail_id[]" value="5">
```

but when i try this.

```
$('[name="comp_detail_id[]"]').get(0).val();
```

i get this.

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).get(...).val is not a function(…)
```

I have no idea what is happening since i though get returns the current object when chaining.

Comment: `$.fn.get()` returns an array of DOM nodes, you want to use `$.fn.eq()`: `$('[name="comp_detail_id[]"]').eq(0).val();`. In case of getting first one, you could just use for readability `$('[name="comp_detail_id[]"]').fisrt().val();` And as `val()` getter returns only first matched element in set value, this would work too: `$('[name="comp_detail_id[]"]').val();`

Comment: `.get(0)` will yield a javascript node object. It wont have a function `.val()` in its prototype.

Comment: @j08691 i'd more expecting this question beeing closed because of dupe

Comment: The 0 there actually is a variable sir so i want it to be like this get(n). Sorry if the question was really bad.

Comment: @ErrolPaleracio or you can use `.get(0).value` instead of `.get(0).val();`

Comment: @ErrolPaleracio Your question isn't 'really bad'... So use `.eq(n)` instead of `.get(n)`. Using `.get()`, it should be `.get(n).value` but mixing plain js with jq synthax is usually not recommended

Comment: Then use `.eq(n)` where n is your variable.

Comment: How do i mark this question as closed or answered sir?